# How come in this code to find prime numbers, is_prime(9) returns True?

Tags: python, primes

```
def is_prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    return False
  else:
    for n in range(2, x):
      if x % n == 0:
        return False
      else:
        return True
```

`print is_prime(9)` returns `True` instead of `False`.

I don't quite understand.

The `range (2,9)` includes this list: `2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

and `9 % 3 == 0`,
So how come I do not get `False` as the answer of that function?

Comment: The `else:
        return True` should have one level of indent less (yes, you read that right). Also you should run the loop from `range(2, int(x ** .5))`

Comment: Because your loop only executes once, for 9 % 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't actually loop, as you return True during the first cycle (9 % 2 == 0 is False).

Something like this should solve the problem:

```python
def is_prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    return False
  for n in range(2, x):
    if x % n == 0:
      return False
  return True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the logic a good amount by keeping your original loop and not exiting early. You can add your first conditional to your final return:

```
def is_prime(x):
  for n in range(2, x):
    if x % n == 0:
      return False

  return x > 2
```

BTW, the Sieve of Erastothenes is a pretty cool method of solving this problem in a much better run time complexity. Here's a link to a brief explanation:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58799/why-in-sieve-of-erastothenes-of-n-number-you-need-to-check-and-cross-out-numbe

Comment: With this code, negative numbers, 0 and 1 will be considered as prime whereas they aren't

Comment: Great point, I made the terrible assumption the caller would take that into consideration. Added a fix.